# Run ionic app in a background mode

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have developed an ionic app using angularjs. Now my app is working perfectly if I do not close my app, however functionality of my app is like an alarm so I need to trigger it from background as well even after user closed the app. So how can I achieve this.

I have even found this
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode

but I am not sure that how to use this along with angularjs. Or if you know any other way to achieve this then please share. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i am assuming you are making some kind of reminder app which show you some popup or `in app notification` you have to configure first background enable mood and then call your function in background

Comment: yes, its a kind of reminder app. So how can I configure background enable mode ?

Answer (score 1):

First Install this plugin
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode#examples

then

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
    // Android customization
    cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.setDefaults({ text:'Doing heavy tasks.'});
    // Enable background mode
    cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();

    // Called when background mode has been activated
    cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.onactivate = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            // Modify the currently displayed notification
            cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.configure({
                text:'Running in background for more than 5s now.'
            });
        }, 5000);
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, but where do I need to put this as my app is in angularJs. So in my angular code where do I need to place this code ?